# numnom Math Game for Younglings game does not start in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: games

[Termnal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pFGV.png) numnom Math Game for Younglings game does not start in Ubuntu 20.04.

I downloaded it from Ubuntu 20.04 app store (snapstore)

Running `numnom` in a terminal outputs an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: Did you try opening it from a terminal? Post the terminal output.

Comment: please tell me, my friend. how to open or start the software(or app or game) through the terminal. my game name is numnom

Comment: It seems you just type `numnom` in the terminal to run it.

Comment: not work,(show error:- Segmentation fault (core dumped))

Comment: right, that's what we wanted to know. But unfortunately that error is not very informative - it just means the program crashed, probably because of a bug